# How to make the following absolutely positioned modal always appear in the center (no matter where the user has scrolled)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't use position fixed because my app should be embedded in websites (right now, the size is 800px x 800px). So I'm using `position: absolute`. However, if the user scrolls too much to the bottom, he won't see the modal if it appears at the top of the app.

And so, I did this:

```
// vreditor-sdk is the outermost container
const currentScrollTop = document.querySelector('.vreditor-sdk').scrollTop
this.emement.style.top: currentScrollTop
```

This makes the modal appear like this (no matter where the user as scrolled):

[image]

But how to make it so that the modal appears in the middle of the 800px x 800px container regardless of where the user has scrolled?

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed;`, then you don't need to use the javascript to position it.

```
.vreditor-sdk {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
.content {
  height: 5000px;
}
.vreditor-sdk {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="vreditor-sdk">
 pop up
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use position fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```css
html {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.vreditor-sdk {
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
    background:#ff0000;
    padding:10px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="vreditor-sdk">
  Fixed with absolute
  </div>
  <p>
  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin risus nunc, hendrerit vel suscipit sit amet, volutpat at purus. Fusce eu mauris pretium, sodales erat sed, fringilla purus. Donec pellentesque diam urna, varius malesuada libero ornare eu. Phasellus finibus tempor fringilla. Aenean eros est, porta vitae massa at, vulputate pulvinar libero. Nullam iaculis rutrum vulputate. Ut suscipit purus sed lorem aliquam, vitae commodo sem ornare. Quisque tristique, elit quis rutrum varius, ipsum metus blandit dui, vitae consectetur enim neque eu metus. Sed efficitur at quam eu congue. Nunc mattis massa sit amet tincidunt luctus. Nulla luctus eros ac ligula sagittis varius. Vestibulum sed tellus at felis molestie vulputate.

Cras porttitor lorem eu felis efficitur varius. Nam rhoncus scelerisque turpis a malesuada. Sed finibus lobortis felis ut ultrices. Phasellus in dui sed mi pretium varius. Suspendisse sit amet elit cursus, sodales dui ac, sodales nunc. Maecenas ac enim interdum massa fringilla laoreet. Mauris urna leo, suscipit vitae diam in, porttitor consequat magna. Nam euismod feugiat nibh. Pellentesque ut pharetra ante, vitae semper justo. Vestibulum ac ipsum nec lorem efficitur rhoncus non nec turpis. Proin quis velit faucibus, imperdiet eros eu, bibendum nunc. Proin elementum et ipsum a tempus. Pellentesque nec tellus bibendum eros mattis egestas et ac lorem. Quisque turpis nunc, lacinia dignissim sapien id, hendrerit facilisis massa.

Nam ut commodo leo, sit amet efficitur ante. Duis bibendum pretium aliquam. Morbi rhoncus pellentesque odio, non molestie sapien luctus quis. Donec id libero arcu. Vivamus ac dignissim ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras odio lorem, sollicitudin ac arcu et, lacinia auctor leo. Nullam laoreet blandit mauris, non pellentesque ipsum consectetur non.

Donec efficitur risus quis justo dignissim malesuada. Sed quis rhoncus ex, vel luctus diam. Nullam finibus, orci at ultricies bibendum, lectus quam tempus est, at vulputate quam enim eget odio. Donec elit est, luctus eget tellus ac, venenatis convallis lorem. Quisque placerat metus a sem consectetur suscipit. Suspendisse auctor mollis velit non semper. Nam metus urna, tempus vitae enim eu, bibendum fringilla augue. Fusce luctus neque eu vehicula finibus. Proin ultricies orci eu lorem pharetra dapibus. Vestibulum sollicitudin erat quis ante ultricies pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nunc feugiat ex sapien, non malesuada nisi porttitor ut. Nam tempus, eros in pharetra pulvinar, augue tellus feugiat lorem, id tincidunt mauris lacus nec eros. Cras in mattis nisl, nec consequat ligula. Mauris arcu odio, tristique vel eleifend a, fermentum non nisl. Nullam volutpat sed felis id tincidunt. Donec tempor dui in urna aliquam viverra. Aenean eget egestas nibh. Sed vestibulum aliquet eros quis tincidunt. 
  </p>
</div>
```